# Git-History of a file, that was modified by git merge -s subtree

Tags: git, git-merge, git-history

How can I get git log to show me the entire history of a file when even `git log -M --follow --full-history new/directory/file` failed.

But first a bit of context on the changes not showing...

We imported a git repository inside another one, we proceeded like so:

```
git clone git@domain.com:namespace/NewRepository
cd NewRepository
git remote add oldRepository git@domain.com:oldNamespace/oldRepository.git
git fetch oldRepository
git checkout -b old-master oldRepository/master
mkdir -p new/directory/
git mv -k * new/directory/
find . -name ".*" -d 1 -exec git mv -k {} new/directory/ \;
git commit -m "Move oldRepository to its new location"
git push --set-upstream origin old-master
git checkout master
git pull
git merge old-master --allow-unrelated-histories
git push
```

So far so good, after this a `git log --follow new/directory/file` would give me the complete changelog of the file.

About a week later, some new changes to the old repository needed to be "pulled" into the new one. We proceeded like so :

```
git fetch --all
git checkout old-master; 
git merge origin/old-master; # I got no conflict (No change actually)
git merge origin/master; # I got no conflict (As expected)

git merge -s subtree -X patience oldRepository/master; 
# I am not sure "-X patience" is a thing but that's what we ran.
# But the "-s subtree" is the important part I believe, we got no conflict and all expected changes were found in their new location (Even newly created files)

git push --set-upstream origin old-master
```

I then created a PR, and then eventually merged it, using the *create a merge commit* option.

Now if I do `git log --follow new/directory/file` the latest commit I see is: `Move old repository to its new location`, but I do not get any newer entry from the old repository that was done after the original import. Despite the changes being present in the file.

However :

- A `git blame new/directory/file` does show me next to the modified line the proper info
- A `git log` (With no file specified) does show me the commit
- A `show history` in my IDE does show me the log entry.

Since my IDE does it, I am guessing there is a combination of flags for git log to show me the proper history, but I tried **A LOT** of combination and could not figure out. And yes I did read the man page...

Additionally, if a different procedure could have prevented me to get into this situation I would like to know... Doe in retrospect maybe the *old-master* branch was unnecessary, but originally it seemed like a good idea to have a branch to resolve conflict.

Thanks!

Comment: Was the file moved at that breaking point?

Comment: (typo) `git --follow` should be `git log --follow`, right ?

Comment: yes, thank you LeGEC

Comment: "Was the file moved at that breaking point?" Not really the file was moved as part of the original import, from both a different repository but also from its path location from / to /new/directory. However, at the breaking point, the file was already at its current location. But the merge got the content from the old directory and location and applied the change to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

If the merge commit did not introduce extra modifications on the target file, `git log new/directory/file` will not display the merge commit itself (which may be a bit disturbing), and depending on the order it chooses to display the commits, the commits from your `old-master` branch may be further down the `log` list.

Try adding the `--graph` option :

```
git log --graph --follow new/directory/file
# or
git log --graph --oneline --follow new/directory/file
```

and see if you have a clearer view of the commits that modified that file.

You may also try the `--date-order`, `--author-date-order` and `--topo-order` flags.

---

[edit] when I first read your question, I somehow thought that the `new/directory` was also created and pushed on `oldRepository`. So I inferred the modifications in `oldRepository` were applied to `new/directory/file`, and I found thus surprising that git would not list the history of `new/directory/file`.

I now understand that, in `oldRepository`, the path to file is `/file`, and that including the new commits as part of `git log --follow new/directory/file` relies on git heuristics to find renames.

Regarding options in `git log`, have you tried :

- using `-C` and `--find-copies-harder` ?
- setting a lower detection threshold using `-M` ? (default is 50%, `-M40%` for example) ?
- if crlf line endings were to differ between the two repos : `--ignore-cr-at-eol` ?
- setting options to ignore whitespace changes: `--ignore-whitespace-at-eol` or `-b` ?

Regarding "renaming" in git : you certainly are aware that git does not track renaming in its history, it just tracks the content you tell it to store.
When it displays a "renaming" in `git log` or `git status` or ... it actually tries to guess what files could have been renamed be looking at the diff between the global content. The `-M50%` option, for example, says that it will consider that `file B` was possibly "moved" from `file A` if 50% of the files are the same.

Comment: No sorry, it's not an ordering issue, the commit is nowhere to be found!

Comment: If you don't filter by filename, you do see the commit, correct ?

Comment: Yes I do see the commit if I do not filter by filename.

Comment: You can inspect `git diff --name-status <that hash> <merge commit hash>`, to see if diff detects a rename.

Comment: It shows the file as being added, but it was already there... `A.   new/directory/file`

Comment: Is there a line mentioning the deletion of `old/directory/file` ?

Comment: "Is there a line mentioning the deletion of old/directory/file ?" No

Comment: -C --find-copies-harder & -M did not help... And there was EOL type change.

Comment: "And there was EOL type change" : does `--ignore-cr-at-eol` help ?

Comment: Sorry I meant: And there was NO EOL type change. And --ignore-cr-at-eol does not change anything.